# How to make sure [BsonId] field is named like property name in the database instead of `_id`

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using Mongo for some denormalized data storage, however found a minor annoyance that I would like to get fixed.

Since my objects have their own `RegistrationCode` which are unique for every record I would like to use that as `ID` so I just add `[BsonId]`. So far so good.

However when I look into actual database I see that this field is not `RegistrationCode` but instead `_id`. How can I make sure that it's named correctly in the actual database?

```
public class Company
{
    [BsonId]
    public string RegistrationCode { get; set; } // Why is this named "_id" in the database?
    // ...
}
```

[image: db]

Comment: Mongo requires field named _id as unique primary key, that's what BsonId refers to (whatever is property name you are applying it to).

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure I did add document without "_id" field in the past.

Comment: Well you can see yourself in mongo documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-id-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Evk stated, every document in a Mongo collection must have an _id field - see [MongoDB Reference Glossary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-id).

Essentially what you are doing when adding the '[BsonId]' attibute is assigning the value of your RegistrationCode property to the _id field.

By convention you should add an Id field to your POCO class which will still allow you to still be able to query/insert/update/remove/index on your unique RegistrationCode field.

```
public class Company
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; } //By convention

    public string RegistrationCode { get; set; } 
    // ...
}
```